# I can't set background images in visual studio code in Kali Linux

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

I want to set background images in my visual studio code, but I can't set background images. Please help me to set visual studio code background images in Kali Linux. This JSON file isn't working.

```
{
"background.enabled":true,
"background.loop":false,
"background.useDefault":false,
"background.useFront":false,
"background.style":{
    "content":"''",
    "pointer-events":"none",
    "position":"absolute",
    "z-index":"99999",
    "width":"70%",
    "height":"100%",
    "margin-left":"30%",
    "background-position":"right",
    "background-size":"cover",
    "background-repeat":"no-repeat",
    "opacity":0.1
},
"background.customImages":[
    "background": "/media/hun73r/New-Volume/wallpapers/kali-linux.jpg",
]
```

}

Comment: where do you use this JSON file, which background image do you want to set?

Comment: I use it settings.json file

Comment: there are no settings with the word `background`, where in the VSC doc have you found `background` stuff